# How to avoid line breaks in MS visio 2010?

Tags: diagram, visio, activity-diagram, visio-2010

I have a simple Activity diagram as below:

[image]

I the decision box, As you can see the 'Correct Credentials?' is broken in two lines. How to avoid them? I searched on the web, but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visio wraps the text to make it fit into the shape. You can just make the text font smaller, or you can use "Text block" tool to set the text position you want:

[image]